# Mocking php POST input

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a script that is getting POST data using

```
$payload = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

I want to use phpunit and mock the POST data. Is there a way I can do this? Maybe with the `$_POST` variable? I am fine with changing the way the script gets the POST data - im just not sure how I can change it so I can mock POST data for testing.

Comment: Most often in situations like this you should write a service that fetches that input, and then mock it for testing purposes instead, unless there's a really good reason to tightly couple your script to `php://input`.

Comment: ...I can't believe I didn't think to create a class and inject it. Working with legacy makes me forget the most basic testing principles sometimes

Comment: @myol can you elaborate what you meant on your comment? I am unsure how you solved your problem. I am facing the same situation.

Comment: I recreated a service class which used file_get_contents so I mocked the class rather than the php function itself

Answer (score -3):

For Google Chrome, there is an extension called `Modify Headers`, which will allow you to intercept a page before it reaches it's *destination*...

Once you have intercepted, you can modify `Request & Response Headers` data.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. I believe that myol is asking about automated unit testing under phpunit rather than manual testing via browser.

Comment: @CollinD - Thank you; as soon as I read your response I realized :-/